# Uploading files with TorBrowser - is it possible?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Is there something about the design of TorBrowser that blocks the ability to upload files to Web sites, or is there something wrong with my TorBrowser installation?

UPDATE:  I figured out that TorBrowser won't access files that aren't on a local drive.  When I copied the files I was trying to upload to the Desktop, everything went fine - but attempting to access `\\\SERVER\SHARE\file.ext` fails silently.  It also fails reading HTML files this way, which still leaves the question:  Why?

Comment: Must be your installation because I'm able to upload files through Tor all the time.

Comment: Normally not a problem if the file is not too big. Btw: Tor isn’t designed for up/downloading huge files. VPN or i2P would be better in this case.

Comment: Have you tried to split your file ?

Comment: It seems like a security measure to refuse access of non-local files. Otherwise specially crafted URLs might cause a leak.